# Setting background of view to an image that is able to pinch zoom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, xcode7

I have created a game where a map is on the screen. With this map I would like to have buttons to change scenes and preform actions. The map I have on the screen I would like to be the full screen with pinch zoom capability, along with capability of a button or label to be on top of the image, without the button being zoomed in on or below the scroll view. I tried using a UIScroll View but the button kept zooming in and going below the image. How can I set the background of my View to a pinch zoomable image with labels and buttons on top not being effected in swift and xcode 7?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, but by calling the method touchesDidBegin() you can move the objects like the TextField and the buttons to a new view that is above the scrollview. Then when touchesDidEnd() you can move them back into the scrollview.